# Histogram - Index must be a positive integer or logical

Tags: matlab, histogram, normalization, dicom

I do the histogram normalization. When I try with another image `lena256.bmp`, the code is running. But when I try with another image it will show error:

> Attempted to access ; index must be a positive integer or logical.
>   Error in `test2` (line 10)
>   `Histo(a(n,m)+1)=Histo(a(n,m)+1)+1;`

Here's the code :

```
a = dicomread('011fp5_256.dcm');
a = double(a);  
a=a/max(a(:)); 
figure; imshow(a);
figure; imhist(a); 
[N, M] = size(a);  
Histo(1:256) = 0;   
for n = 1 : N   
    for m = 1 : M
        Histo(a(n,m)+1) = Histo(a(n,m)+1)+1;  
    end
end
Histo = Histo/(N*M);
figure; plot(Histo);
```

Comment: Can't see the code, maybe you forget to post

Comment: Don't put your inside links. Just post them with your question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the matrix index can't be a decimal value, therefore, you need to approximate the `a(n,m)` to the nearest integer value.

```
a = dicomread('CT-MONO2-16-ankle.dcm');
a = double(a);  
a=a/max(a(:)); 
figure; imshow(a);
figure; imhist(a); 
[N, M] = size(a);  
Histo(1:256) = 0;   
for n = 1 : N   
    for m = 1 : M
        if a(n,m)+1 ~= floor(a(n,m)+1)%I use this code for find the error
            disp(a(n,m)+1);
        end
        ind = floor(a(n,m)+1);% apprx. to the nearest integer.
        Histo(ind) = Histo(ind)+1;  
    end
end
Histo = Histo/(N*M);
figure; plot(Histo);
```